# get US Census regions using states

Tags: python, database, pandas, geography

The US Census designates each state to a [region](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/maps/reference/us_regdiv.pdf) (ie New York is in NorthEast). I have a dataset of states for which I would like to look up the states' corresponding US Census region.

The [`us`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/us) module was my first attempt but it doesn't contain the region (to my awareness). The [`census`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/census) module provides an API to the US Census but I don't see a way to query the region. Short of having to manually construct a dictionary, does anyone know of a convenient way?

#### Data sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['Alabama','Georgia','California','Tennessee',
 'Florida','Illinois','Arizona','New York','Maryland','Virginia','New Jersey','Kansas',
 'District of Columbia','Texas','Missouri','North Carolina','Ohio','Massachusetts',
 'Wisconsin','Pennsylvania','Alaska','Michigan',
 'Arkansas']})
df.loc[:,'region'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some one made a nice [table](https://github.com/cphalpert/census-regions/blob/master/us%20census%20bureau%20regions%20and%20divisions.csv) on github. That you can copy and paste in as a dataframe

```
pd.read_clipboard()
```

Comment: The `pd.read_clipboard()` isn't always stable (sometimes crashes my notebooks). To avoid from reading from the clipboard, one could simply click on the "Raw" button to download the dataset in a csv format.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the link is stable (which it may not be of course) you can get by with reading the csv directly:

```
pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cphalpert/census-regions/master/us%20census%20bureau%20regions%20and%20divisions.csv')
```

For the record, should you need to go back to the horse's mouth for these, you can get them from the Census Bureau's TIGER GIS files.

Install `geopandas` to be able to easily load geographic shapefiles, download the state file, whatever [vintage](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/STATE/tl_2017_us_state.zip), and do like so:

```
states = gpd.read_file('/Users/akselo/downloads/tl_2017_us_state.shp')
states.set_index(['NAME'])[['REGION','DIVISION']].head()
```

`REGION   DIVISION
West Virginia      3        5
Florida            3        5
Illinois           2        3
Minnesota          2        4
Maryland           3        5`

Comment: +1 for mentioning `geopandas` and suggesting the use of TIGER GIS files. I wasn't aware of either and it's a convenient solution. Thanks!